# Error on FsUnit example

Tags: f#, fsunit

I copied this example from the FsUnit [project page](http://fsunit.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=fsunit):

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit
let [<Test>] trivial () = 1 |> should not (equal 2)
```

F# gives me the following error:

> Error 2   This expression was expected to have type
>       bool     but here has type Constraints.EqualConstraint
>
> Error 1   The type 'bool' is not compatible with the type 'Constraints.Constraint'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know FsUnit, but you seemed to forget test annotation: `let [<Test>] trivial() = 1 |> should not (equal 2)`.

Comment: Also, unit tests should be functions, not values. Not sure if this is the cause of your error, but you're missing a `()` that pad's example has.

Comment: yeah, I forgot both those things when I went to type up this question. Good catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A newer version of FsUnit includes a change that renames the `FsUnit.not` function to `FsUnit.not'`. This should eliminate the conflict with the built-in `not` function. You can get the latest version from [NuGet Gallery](http://nuget.org/packages?q=fsunit). Examples of use can be found on the FsUnit [GitHub site](https://github.com/dmohl/FsUnit/blob/master/Examples/NUnit/BowlingGame.fsx).

Let me know if you still see the issue. I'll be happy to do some more in-depth troubleshooting with you.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is something wrong with the way you're referencing `FsUnit`. I tried to run your code (just copy `FsUnit` source code from CodePlex) and it worked fine. You still need to write your test as a function (as pointed out by Joel) so write something like `let [<Test>] trivial () = ...`.

For some reason, I think your script is using the built-in `not` function (that operates on `bool` values) instead of the `FsUnit.not` function that operates on `Constraint` objects. Does it work if you use the `not` function from `FsUnit` explicitly?

```
let cnot = FsUnit.not
let [<Test>] trivial = 1 |> should cnot (equal 1)
```